# How do you make a loading symbol

Tags: javascript, html, css

My page loads pretty slowly, so I would like to add a loading symbol. I have a loading image, and now I would just like to make it so that the page displays the loading symbol, until it loads. How do I do this?

Comment: Do not propose jQuery solutions to questions not so tagged.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div block with your image and enclose the rest of the content in another div:

```
<div id='loadingDiv'>
    Loading...  <img src='path to loading image' />
 </div> 
<div id='content'>
...
</div>
```

Make sure that in css #content is set to display: hidden;

Then add the following js:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    $('#loadingDiv').hide();
    $('#content').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the div right below the opening body tag.

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

Now add the CSS for the class

```
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('images/page-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat /*image that you want to show at loading time */rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

After that just add this script in the head section of your HTML page..

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
</script>
```

Comment: `<script>` tag does not require `type="text/javascript"`.